#  to plot two different graphs together on the same chart

Tags: c#, graph, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I am using the MSChart Control to plot some data but I would like to plot two different graphs
together on the same chart. For example, use a Bar chart (series1) with a pie chart (series2)

i am trying to show the two different graphs using one single chart by using following code
 It was showing data correct  but one problem is i want to show the two graphs (PIE CHART , BAR CHART )  but it was showing ("TWO PIE Charts")

Can any one help on this

NOte : I am using one chart for all these operations

```
  private void kpicartmouse_click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    Series acceptseries;
    Series membershiptypeseries = null;
      Title title;
    string area;

  try
  {
    var pos = e.Location;
    var results = kpiChartControl.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
      if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
      {


        DataTable visits = null;
        visits = KPIData.Visits(dtStartDate.Value,dtEndDate.Value, mf);

        DataTable accepts = null;
        accepts = KPIData.AcceptedvisitsByMembership(mf);

        area = "subchart";
        kpiChartControl.ChartAreas.Add(area);
        acceptseries = kpiChartControl.Series.Add(area);
        acceptseries.ChartArea = area;

        title = kpiChartControl.Titles.Add("Accepted Visits By MemberShip Type");
        title.DockedToChartArea = area;
        title.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
        title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        kpiChartControl.Titles.Add("").DockedToChartArea = area;
        kpiChartControl.Titles.Add("Accepted visits by memebrship types").DockedToChartArea = area;



        foreach (Title titles in kpiChartControl.Titles)
        {
          titles.IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
        }

        foreach (ChartArea chartArea in kpiChartControl.ChartAreas)
        {
          chartArea.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
          chartArea.Area3DStyle.Inclination = 45;
          //chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = !overview;
        }

        foreach (Series chartSeries in kpiChartControl.Series)
        {
          chartSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
          chartSeries["ColumnDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";
          chartSeries["LabelStyle"] = "Top";
          chartSeries.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
          chartSeries.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;
        }
        foreach (Series chartSeries in kpiChartControl.Series)
        {
          chartSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

          chartSeries["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
          chartSeries["DoughnutRadius"] = "30";
          chartSeries["PieDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";

          chartSeries.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;
        }





        foreach (Legend legend in kpiChartControl.Legends)
        {
          legend.Enabled = false;
        }

        if (accepts == null)
        {
          acceptseries.Points.Clear();
          acceptseries.Points.AddXY("no live", 0);
        }
        if (visits == null)
        {
          membershiptypeseries.Points.Clear();
          membershiptypeseries.Points.AddXY("no membershiptypes", 0);


        }

        kpiChartControl.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(accepts.Rows, "mshipname", accepts.Rows, "Value");
        kpiChartControl.Series["subchart"].Points.DataBindXY(visits.Rows, "Status", visits.Rows, "Visits");



        foreach (Series chartSeries in kpiChartControl.Series)
        {
          foreach (DataPoint point in chartSeries.Points)
          {

            switch (point.AxisLabel)
            {
              case "Accepted": point.Color = Color.Green; break;
              case "Refused": point.Color = Color.Red; break;

            }
            point.Label = string.Format("{0:0}", point.YValues[0]);
          }

        }

        foreach (Series chartSeries in kpiChartControl.Series)
        {
          foreach (DataPoint point in chartSeries.Points)
          {

            switch (point.AxisLabel)
            {
              case "Silver membership": point.Color = Color.Green; break;
              case "Gold Membership": point.Color = Color.Blue; break;
              //case "Refused": point.Color = Color.Red; break;
              case "Weekend Peak": point.Color = Color.Cyan; break;
              case "prspect": point.Color = Color.Indigo; break;


            }
            point.Label = string.Format("{0:0}- {1}", point.YValues[0], point.AxisLabel);
          }

        }





      }
    }
  }
  catch
  {
  }


}
```

Comment: why you are  giving -1 tell the reason otherwise don't downvote

Comment: is my question  is unclear.....

Comment: can any one pls help me on ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess... won't this block of code force all your charts to be Pie charts?

```
    foreach (Series chartSeries in kpiChartControl.Series)
    {
      chartSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

      chartSeries["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";
      chartSeries["DoughnutRadius"] = "30";
      chartSeries["PieDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";

      chartSeries.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;
    }
```

---

If this doesn't help, then try breaking your code down into smaller methods, then commenting each bit out in turn - then you'll be able to understand what each bit does.

Comment: May be ..... but   if i remove the above block all graphs will be bar charts there is no pie chart that is what i dont want .. I need two different charts(PIE CHART , BAR chart)......

Comment: do you know what a `foreach` loop is and what it does?

Comment: seriously, you need to read and understand that code - that code says "set all my series to be pie charts"

Comment: yes  when you want to repeat a set of statements for each element of a collection or array we can use foreach loop

Comment: how can i differentiate two different areas in same page for plotting two different graphs

Comment: You already have two references to acceptseries and membershiptypeseries - why not call different methods on them? (over and out)

Comment: acceptseries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie; membershiptypeseries .ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn; ?

Comment: foreach (Series chartSeries in kpiChartControl.Series)
          {
            foreach (DataPoint point in chartSeries.Points)
            {

              switch (point.AxisLabel)
              {
                case "Accepted": point.Color = Color.Green; break;
                case "Refused": point.Color = Color.Red; break;

              }
              point.Label = string.Format("{0:0}", point.YValues[0]);
            }

          }   at this place do i need to change any thing

Comment: seriously, you need to read and understand your code - think through what each line does and what the whole code needs to do

Comment: StUart would you pls look at this  question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760258/trying-to-position-the-footer

Comment: Link not found user682417